# Clojure to test for blank, safe for non-collections

Tags: clojure

```
(= [true false true false]
   (for [x [nil true [] [true]]] (_____ x)))
```

Fill in the blank please! `empty?` is very close but `(empty? true)` throws an exception. There has to be a better way than catching that?

Something like `(or (and (seq? v) (empty? v)) (and (not (seq? v)) (not (nil? v)))))` fails on `[]` because `(seq? [])` is false.

Comment: Try `coll?` instead of `seq?`.

Answer (score 1):

Internet points to exupero.

`(or (nil? v) (and (coll? v) (empty? v)))`